# Check from multiple drowpdowns dynamically created if not selected alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, dropdown

So I have a list of dropdown selections dynamically created from a database and I would like to check for each of them if something is selected, if not, do an alert and do not submit.

This is the code for the dropdowns

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
<div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?> btn-group">
  <label class="control-label text-uppercase " for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
  <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
    <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="filepicker" id="btncheck" value="Continue">
```

And the this is the JS:

```
$('#btncheck')
 .click(function(){
  if ($("select")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Please select option");
            return false;
 }
});
```

It works only if none of the dropdowns are selected but I would like to be able to check each of them individually and pop an alert for each dropwdown if not selected or if one of them is not selected, any idea how to do that?

**UPDATE:**

Ok I have manage to get the alert and submission to return false if any of the dropdown is not selected, but now I get an alert for each of the one that are not selected... if I have 10 dropdowns that will be a lot of alert popping up... how can I have only one alert but still check each of them...? Or or can I say in the alert message which dropdown is it?

See the JS I used:

```
$('#optionForm').submit(function(event)
{
  $('select').each(function()
  {
    if($(this).val() === "")
    {
      alert( "Please complete selection options!" );
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How many select are you supposed to have?

Comment: Checking selectedIndex is very dorky way to check if the option was selected or not, especially when you have the 1st option tag with value="". Just use if(!$('select').val())

Comment: You do not need to put opening and closing PHP tags around each line of PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update, you can use a temporary variable to check each DDL but have only one message.

```
$('#optionForm').submit(function(event)
{
    var isValid = true;

    $('select').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() === "")
        {
             isValid = false;
             return false;
        }
    });

    if(!isValid)
    {
         alert( "Please complete selection options!" );
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thansk! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your collection of `select`s.

```
$('#btncheck').click(function() 
{ 
    $('select').each(function() 
    { 
        if ( $(this).val() == "" )  
        {
            alert("Please select option");
            return false;
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each dropdowns using a loop like this :

```
$('#btncheck').click(function()
{
    $('select').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() === "")
        {
            alert("Please select option");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You can also add specifics CSS classes in order to guide the user to determine which dropdown is concerned by the message.

```
 $('#btncheck').click(function()
{
    $('select').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() === "")
        {
            $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            alert("Please select option");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, seems to work for the alert but not for the submit... I don't want it to submit once the alert comes up... not sure why it still submitting

Comment: Instead of listening to the click event on the button, you can listen to the submit event on the form : https://api.jquery.com/submit/ : `$('#form').submit(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

PHP code:

added `<span class="help-inline danger"></span>` after select field to show error.

```
<?php if($options){ ?>
  <?php foreach($options as $option){ ?>
    <?php if($option['type'] == 'select'){ ?>
      <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required']?' required':''); ?> btn-group">
        <label class="control-label text-uppercase " for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
        <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
          <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
          <?php foreach($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <span class="help-inline danger"></span>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="filepicker" id="btncheck" value="Continue">
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
  $('#optionForm').submit(function(event){
    var errors = false;
    $('select').each(function(index){
      if($(this).val() == ""){
        /* add required error. */
        $(this).closest('.help-inline').html('This field is required.');
        errors = true;
      }else{
        /* remove required error. */
        $(this).closest('.help-inline').html('');
      }
      /* we can hide/show error message instead of updating html */
    });

    if(errors){
      /* don't submit error found */
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
</script>
```